# Event delegation .on('click') and the css negation :not()

Tags: jquery, css, events, delegation, negation

I am trying to create an event delegation for a dynamically added/removed class. I am creating an event for specific elements that are clicked and don't have that class added to them.

Here's my line of code but it's not working. Is my syntax wrong? If so what would the proper way be to fix this code?

```
$('.gallery-cell a img').off('click').on('click', ':not(.g-clicked)', function() { 
    // more code here 
});
```

Comment: There's nothing inherently wrong with what little you've shown. We'd need a more complete example of both your JS and HTML to be of any help.

Comment: Okay thank you. I just wanted to confirm that this line of code is correct and I can put :not() where it is. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second argument in the [`$selector.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) is a filter for the **decendants** of your $selector. Since `img` can't have children, you most likely want to do something like this (depending on which item you dynamically add your class):

```
$('.gallery-cell a').on('click', 'img:not(.g-clicked)', function() { 
    // more code here 
});
```

or

```
$('.gallery-cell').on('click', 'a:not(.g-clicked) img', function() { 
    // more code here 
});
```